# string: descend sorting - cell array

Tags: string, matlab, sorting, data-structures, cell-array

For the following code:

```
country(1).name='USA';
country(2).name='Spain';
country(3).name='France';
% descending order
[~,index]=sort({country.name},'descend');
country=country(index);
for i=1:3
    fprintf('name = %s\n',  country(i).name)
end
```

I have the following strange error when using sort for cells such as string name in descending order:

```
Error using sort
DIM and MODE arguments not supported for cell arrays.
Error in sandbox (line 43)
[~,index]=sort({country.name},'descend');
```

It works nicely for string if is ascending order, and with numerical value it works either ascending and descending sorting.

According to what I searched [online](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/291703) and tried, the syntax would be expected to be working. But it is not working only for string in descending order.

The output for descending order should look like:

```
name = USA
name = Spain
name = France
```

Any suggestions or idea on how to get it fixed for the type of data struct with cells that my program is using? All comments are warmly welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html#inputarg_direction) (and the error message):

> `direction` is not supported when `A` is a cell array, that is, `sort` only
>   sorts in ascending order.

You can use [`flip`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flip.html) to work around this:

```
country(1).name='USA';
country(2).name='Spain';
country(3).name='France';
% descending order
[~,index]=sort({country.name});
country=flip(country(index));
for i=1:3
    fprintf('name = %s\n',  country(i).name)
end
```

Which prints:

```
name = USA
name = Spain
name = France
```

Comment: but what if I wanted to print in ''descend'': like from Z to A - which is exactly the case not working? your solution is printing from A to Z - for ascending order it works with no problem as I mentioned in my post. thank you!

Comment: Sorry, it's `fliplr`, not `flipud`. Or, more generically, `flip`. `index` is a row vector so `flipud` doesn't actually change it.

Comment: thank you very much indeed! sorting and after it apply flip work nicely!